# What is the replacement of MvcMiddleware in ASP.NET Core 3.0+?

Tags: asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core 3.0+, they introduced `EndpointRoutingMiddleware` and `EndpointMiddleware`.

I want to know What is the replacement of `MvcMiddleware` in ASP.NET Core 3.0+?

Is it `Endpoints => MapControllerRoute`? (MapControllerRoute = MvcMiddleware)

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute( /* HERE */
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Is there something that isn't working when using it?

Comment: Actually I am reading ASP.NET Core in Action and it is for version 2.0, In chapter 4 the author is talking about MvcMiddleware so I am trying to map concepts to the latest version. That is the reason I asked the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are essentially correct, endpoint routing changed the way that routing works quite significantly.
Previously, a middleware wouldn't know which action in MVC was going to handle the request because the action selection logic was called from inside `MvcMiddleware`.
Now with endpoint routing, middleware placed after `app.UseRouting();` and before `app.UseEndpoints();` can know what the final endpoint is.
It also removed the need to duplicate things like CORS policies.

Mapping MVC routes is done with `MapControllerRoute()` as you have done.
Attribute routes defined with e.g. `[HttpGet]` are mapped also when you call `MapControllerRoute`.
In case your app only uses attribute routes, you can leave out the arguments to `MapControllerRoute` completely.